# Gnome Shell suddenly automatically scrolling right

Tags: gnome-shell, mouse-scroll

I'm currently using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with Gnome 42.5 Suddenly, whenever I pull up the applications grid the apps scroll all the way to the right without me doing anything. I try to scroll back to the left, but it autoscrolls back. Game also tries to make me use a new workspace if I hit the Super key. I've tried two different mice, and I've tried disconnecting the keyboard, it's not the peripherals. Anyone got an idea what is causing this and how to stop it?